# Excellence as an undergrad Econ major

Tags: united-states, undergraduate, economics

What defines excellence as an undergrad econ major?

I was talking to a few friends in CS and they seem to be very clear on excellence for them - straight As, widely used/well built programs, and a solid understanding of the math behind CS/algos (for interviews). However, I noticed that I am unclear about what excellence as an Econ major is.

Getting straight As is obvious, but I can't think of much more beyond that (perhaps a good senior thesis?). Yet, many people have straight As (or almost straight As) and asking for a groundbreaking paper as a senior thesis seems to be a bit much. Thus, how would I differentiate excellent undergrad econ achievement from merely good undergrad econ achievement?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one measure "widely used/well built programs"?

Comment: @NelsonGon Widely downloaded is perhaps an indicator of _widely used_. _Well-built_ can surely be evaluated by any professional, just like a carpenter can evaluate furniture.

Comment: @NelsonGon user2768 is right but there are also some crossovers (ex. forking a repo - probably useful and well enough built)

Answer (score 1):

Excellence demands outstanding performance, topping the class. Mastery of the subject is required. Best marks are likely, but not necessary; good marks suffice. Outstanding performance goes beyond marks. For example, a broad understanding of a discipline's application to the world, being able to apply knowledge to real problems, a thesis fit for publication (i.e., advancing domain knowledge). A good student will achieve good marks, perhaps the best marks; an excellent student will achieve something beyond marks, such as the examples listed.

Comment: So beyond top marks and understanding the material, the only thing to set apart excellent from good is simply the thesis?

Comment: @qme91143yuoia I gave three examples. There are more.

Comment: I mentioned this in a previous answer, but people downvoted it and I realized it might not be as relevant as it is.  You want to gain relevant __experience__ for success as an econ major.  This could be in the form of internships or relevant research experience.  Something that makes you stand out from the crowd.

Comment: @Daveguy +1 Excellent point, that's something that could be added to my list of examples